# JMenu JMenuCheckboxItem setting to current state

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I have a JMenuCheckboxItem in a JMenu; I want it to reflect the current state of a program option when the JMenu is displayed. I can't figure out where to initialize it. I created an `actionPerformed()` for the JMenu, thinking that would be activated when the menu was displayed, but according to my debugger it is not. Where should I put a call to checkboxMenuItem.setState() so that it reflects the state of the option when the user displays the menu?

Comment: Sorry, found it -- add a Menu Listener (addMenuListener) and implement the menuSelected event. I'm still not sure what an action listener would do for this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can set initial state for the   `JCheckBoxMenuItem`  as follows

```
 JCheckBoxMenuItem chkBoxItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("select me")
    chkBoxItem.setSelected(true);
```

You can also `addActionListener` to the chkBoxItem  and get action command for the chkBoxItem  like `actionEvent.getActionCommand()`

Comment: As I said, I wanted the value as it is when the menu is invoked; initializing it won't necessarily cover the case. And an action listener for the menu item won't do me any good that I can tell, I want to set the value for the menu item, and it would not be invoked until that menu item itself was selected.

Comment: Do you want to set the new value for the JCheckBoxMenuItem ?

Comment: Yes -- as I said in the comment to the original post, I am setting it in the menuSelected method out of the menu listener to the JMenu containing the JCheckboxMenuitem.